# Analyze Code Coverage with Visual Studio skips some projects

Tags: visual-studio-2015, code-coverage, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the Microsoft Unit Tests.

I pick 'Test->Analyze Code Coverage->All Tests' with no runsettings file.  When the code coverage results appear I noticed one project (one dll) is not there.  This is a project with no tests so I would expect it to show 0% coverage.

If I have no unit tests that reference a project will it not be included it in the code coverage results?

I added a quick test project with one test referencing the missing project and it is now included.  We have people adding projects and need to make sure they have tests.  A new project should show 0% if no tests are written.  Is there a way to check all projects and report 0% if we have no tests?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same question. I tried [set that by *.runsettings file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj159530.aspx), that's doesn't work.

For this purpose, I just add empty internal class for Code Coverage. And write a unit test to access this empty class. I know this is not a good idea, but that could achieve this purpose.

Moreover, for testing an internal class. It must add

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("XXXXXXXXX")]
```

in AssemblyInfo.cs.